# Passing Array Into Google Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, charts, google-visualization

I have some records for that I am using three arrays which contains dynamic values.

```
var Results=new Array();
var Second=new Array();
var First=new Array();
```

I want to show these array values in Google chart but as per Google chart they shows array values differently.

How to add my arrays into Google Chart ?

Comment: What is the content in your array..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they are all the same length, you can try something like this:

```
var Combined = new Array();
Combined[0] = ['Results', 'First', 'Second'];
for (var i = 0; i < Results.length; i++){
  Combined[i + 1] = [ Results[i], First[i], Second[i] ];
}
//second parameter is false because first row is headers, not data.
var table = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(Combined, false);
```

[See here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#arraytodatatable) for documentation on array to DataTable.

Comment: Thanks for the solution I also did the same way it resolved my issue.

Comment: I only get the last data on the result. I don't know why.

Comment: I resolve my issue, I have this option on my chart "sliceVisibilityThreshold: .2," and made sure my dataType on my column is as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn('string','Lost Reason');
dataTable.addColumn('number','Value');
dataTable.addRows([
  [lostReason[0], parseInt(lostReasonVal[0])],
  [lostReason[1], parseInt(lostReasonVal[1])],
  [lostReason[2], parseInt(lostReasonVal[2])],
  [lostReason[3], parseInt(lostReasonVal[3])],
]);

console.log('dataTable=' + JSON.stringify(dataTable));

var options = {
    title: 'Lost Reason',
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    backgroundColor: { fill: '#cac9c9' }
};
```